# MacBook Pro (Monterey 12.5.1) periodically loses all network capabilities

Tags: network, monterey, internet

With seemingly increasing frequency, my MacBook Pro (Monterey `12.5.1`, 13", 2019, 2.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5) suddenly loses all network capabilities, meaning I can't load any new websites, all apps that require internet access show a 'disconnected' error, the CPU usage shoots up as everything repeatedly tries and fails to reconnect to the internet. Before I can restart my laptop, numerous apps need to be Force Quit as they stop responding.

I connect to the internet with an ethernet cable via USB-C dongle, tested the same cable/dongle on a different laptop and no problems, so that is unlikely to be problem. I have WiFi turned off while I'm not using it. The only way I've been able to fix this has been restarting the laptop.

When this happened yesterday, I wanted to check System Preferences > Network and was surprised to see a blank menu:

[image: emptynetworkprefs]

When the problem occurred today, the Network preferences appeared as normal. After restarting, everything works again, the Network preferences appears as usual. I've got no idea what causes this to happen, or how to troubleshoot this. Any help or ideas much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on macOS 12.6.1. Happens randomly on my macbook pro 15-inch 2017. Doesn't happen on my iMac or the M1 laptop.

Comment: in the meantime I suspect that it might have something to do with some Fireeye Agent that corporate forces me to have on my work laptop (the process name is `xagt`)